# Difference between using the infinitive form and the gerund form

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

difference between

> "We don't want everybody to know about it."

and

> "We don't want everybody knowing about it."

Answer (score -2):

"want" is an infinitive verb and it can only be followed by (noun/pronoun) to + conjugated form of verb (1). This means that your second sentence isn't correct grammatically.